# Nested ng-repeat doesn't appear angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to list out groups of items in angular using `ng-repeat` and then from those populating the groups items as well. 
For some reason I can get each group repeating and print out its items with a binding `{{ group.items }}`, but when i put that inside of a `ng-repeat` and call it, nothing appears.

Inside my directive

```
angular.module('concierge.customer.menuItems', ['concierge.customer.dollars'])
  .directive('menuItems', [function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        groups: '='
      },
      templateUrl: 'modules/menu_items/menu_items.html'
    }
  }])
```

My View

```
ul.menus.fat
  li(ng-repeat='group in groups' ng-class-even='alt-row')    
    .menu-group-content
      .menu-group-items(ng-show='group.items && group.items.length > 0')
        {{ group.items }} // This line prints the items correctly
        li(ng-repeat='item in group.items')
          {{ item }} // This line Doesn't produce anything
```

An Example `group` in JSON

```
{  
   "items":[  
      {  
         "description":"crispy ling cod, cabbage, salsa fresca, chipotle mayo ",
         "group_id":7,
         "id":25,
         "name":"Fish Taco"
      },
      {  
         "description":"pork al pastor, cheddar, monteray jack, crema ",
         "group_id":7,
         "id":26,
         "name":"Pork Gringa"
      },
      {  
         "description":"avocado, radish, green onion, cilantro, black chile oil ",
         "group_id":7,
         "id":27,
         "name":"Chicken Karaage Taco"
      },
      {  
         "description":"salsa, fresca, crema & queso fresco",
         "group_id":7,
         "id":28,
         "name":"Blackbean Taco"
      }
   ],
   "merchant_id":3,
   "type":"individual",
   "id":7,
   "name":"Single Tacos"
}
```

Why doesn't the second ng-repeat get populated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved this after almost two hours, turns out to be an issue with my DOM structure, since I didn't have any `ul` element's inbetween my `li`'s it broke.

### No display of `{{ item }}`

```
ul.menus.fat
  li(ng-repeat='group in groups' ng-class-even='alt-row')    
    li(ng-repeat='item in group.items')
      {{ item }} // This line Doesn't produce anything
```

### `{{ item }}` displayed

```
ul.menus.fat
  li(ng-repeat='group in groups' ng-class-even='alt-row')  

    ul  // This ul was key
      li(ng-repeat='item in group.items')
        {{ item }} // This line Doesn't produce anything
```